# why i get an assigning error in this code

Tags: python, assign

I wrote "pig_latin" code as below.
In Pig Latin, if a word begins with a consonant, the speaker removes this letter and puts it at the end, followed by “ay.” For example, “pig” becomes “igpay” and “latin” becomes “atinlay.”

```
text = " I am a programmer"
text2 = text.split() #['I', 'am', 'a', 'programmer'] 
text3 = ""
end = text2[1:]
start = text2[0]
for i in text2:
    text3 = end + start
print(text3)
```

I have no idea why this error occurs:

```
text3 = end + start
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: Why do you have a `for`-loop, when it doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append 'ay' at the end of all words that starts with a consonant, you have to Iterate through each word and replace the letters.

```
text = " I am a programmer"
text2 = text.split() #['I', 'am', 'a', 'programmer'] 
text3 = ""

for i in text2:
    # check for consonant
    others = i[1:]
    others  =''.join(others)
    text3 = text3 + others + i[0] + 'ay '
print(text3)
```

If you want to do this for the whole sentence, you can skip the iteration. logic applies the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just debug when you stuck somehwere. in your case if you print

```
print(end)
print(start)
```

It's printing

```
['am', 'a', 'programmer']
I
```

Observation

```
end is - List
start - str
```

you can't concat them

### Code correction

Make string out of end list using [str.join](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and then concat them like so..

```
text = " I am a programmer"
text2 = text.split() #['I', 'am', 'a', 'programmer'] 
text3 = ""
end = text2[1:]
end  =' '.join(end)
start = text2[0]

for i in text2:
    text3 = end + start
print(text3)
```